# How to copy package.json to dist folder without the scripts part

Tags: javascript, json, npm, webpack, package

I'm using webpack to bundle my javascript library and I'm currently copying the `package.json` to the dist folder using [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/).

```
(...)
plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [{
                from: "package.json",
                to: "dist"
            }],
        })
    ],
(...)
```

I was wondering if I could copy the `package.json` without the script tag:

```
{
    "name": "monaco-javascript-compiler",
    "version": (...),
    "description": "(...)",
    "main": (...),
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "debug": "npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=development",
        "build": "npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/RicardoGomesRocha/monaco-javascript-compiler.git"
    },
    "author": "Ricardo Rocha",
    "dependencies": {(...)},
    "devDependencies": {(...)}
}
```

I know a solution that involves using [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to read the `package.json`, remove the script tag from the JSON and output a new file with that JSON, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option called `transform` in `CopyWebpackPlugin`,which allows you to amend the content of the file before copying it to the dist folder.

Checkout the documentation here:
[CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#transform)